# How can I use sleep() and timer in one program?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I want to use `sleep()` and timer in one program.

But when I use `setitimer()` in the program, `sleep()` loses its efficacy.

How can I make a timer while not disturbing `sleep()` to block the main thread?

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple threads running at the same time and you want to use `sleep()` to block the main thread and timer on another? or both `sleep()` and timer in the same thread?

Answer (score 1):

From [`man sleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html):

> sleep()  may be implemented using SIGALRM; mixing calls to alarm(2) and sleep() is a bad idea.

Use [`nanosleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) instead:

> Compared to sleep(3) and usleep(3), nanosleep() has the following advantages: it provides a higher resolution for specifying the sleep interval; POSIX.1 explicitly specifies that it does not interact with signals; and it makes the task of resuming a sleep that has been interrupted by a signal handler easier.